# Insert Environment variable

Tags: linux, environment-variables

Is there any way to insert an Environment variable into a Linux local machine from a website?I just want that when an user clicks on a button from a website,automatically to insert an environment variable into the user linux machine.I need to do this in any web language programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely not possible - for the same reasons that you can't open files in Javascript from the browser.

Another solution is to allow them to download a bash script and run it on their own. You will need to include instructions to run it, of course. (Don't forget to make it executable `chmod +x`)

As a side note, this is probably not a good idea in the first place. You could include literally anything in that bash script, and the user (assuming (s)he can't read bash) would just have to trust you. It is generally not advised to run random bash scripts on your computer or allow websites to make modifications to your environment variables.

Comment: And is there any way to download a script into a computer(running on Linux) without user confirmation ?

Comment: No, the user chooses whether or not to receive download prompts. This is set in their browser settings.